# Dynamic workspaces have stopped working?

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I'm not exactly clear when and have no idea why, but at some point in the last couple of weeks, dynamic workspaces have stopped working on 20.10.  When I log in, I have only a single workspace and to get anything else, I have to open Gnome Tweaks and configure static workspaces, setting a fixed number of workspaces.  Even if I then switch back to dynamic workspaces, I still get the number of workspaces I configured statically.

Has anyone else seen this?  I've tried disabling extensions but this makes no difference.

Answer (score 5):

had just the same problem. this fixed it:

- disable the **auto-move-windows extension** (which modifies the dynamic workspace behavior)
- restart the shell by pressing `Alt+F2`, entering `r` as the command and pressing `Enter`

see
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/487

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04 GNOME 42